# Call Actionfrom other Action

Tags: react-redux

I'm learning React and I've a question on something I've made.
Is it right to call an action from another action ? Is it the best option to do such things ?

```
import * as types from "../types/actionTypes";
import * as consumptionApi from "../../utils/api/consumptionApi";
import * as taskApi from "../../utils/api/taskApi";
import * as taskActions from "../actions/taskActions";

export function loadProjectConsumptionSuccess(consumptions) {
  return { type: types.LOAD_PROJECT_CONSUMPTION_SUCCESS, consumptions };
}

export function loadProjectConsumption(projectId) {
  return async function(dispatch, getState) {
    try {
      let tasks = await taskApi.getTasksByProjectId(projectId);
      dispatch(taskActions.loadTasksByProjectSuccess(tasks));
      tasks = getState().tasks;
      const consumptions = await consumptionApi.getProjectConsumption(tasks);
      dispatch(loadProjectConsumptionSuccess(consumptions));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      throw error;
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in dispatching actions after `await`ing. In fact it used to be the go-to approach for a very long time, especially when code doesn't change a lot.

What you do find as you go on is that you often need to make changes and that it's not the most flexible approach. What people seem to do now is this

```js
// actions.js

export const retrieveData = () => () => fetch(`/url`).then(d => d.json())

export const populateData = (data) => ({ type: 'MODULE_POPULATE_DATA', data })

// inside the component

const dispatch = useDispatch()

useEffect(() => {
  const loadData = async () => {
    const { data } = await dispatch(retrieveData())
    dispatch(populateData(data))
  }

  loadData()
}, [])
```

This other approach leads to some amounts of duplication of code (which is fine) but has access to everything inside the component: props, refs, state, memoized values etc. without having to do weird things to pass them around.